# Is it possible to spread the input array into arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

So Promise.all passes an array as a value into the function, I would much rather it pass the array values as arguments.

Assume I have this function:

```
function printData(a,b,c){
   console.log(a,b,c)
}
```

I would like

```
Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(printData)
>> [1,2,3] undefined undefined
```

To print this instead

```
>> 1 2 3
```

Is there a better way of doing this:

```
Promise.all([1,2,3,4]).then(function(values){printData.apply(null, values)})
```

using the spread operator?

I also tried

```
Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(printData.apply)
```

But it returns an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to use the spread operator technically has you nesting functions, which works, but there is another way

`Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(printData.apply)`

Doesn't work because this is equal to:

```
printData.apply.call(undefined, [1,2,3])
```

which returns the same error

```
>>Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined,
 which is a undefined and not a function
```

---

`Promise` passes `this` in to `call` and it loses track of what it should be.
What you want is:

```
test.apply.call(test,[null,1,2,3])
```

which equals:

```
test.apply(null,[1,2,3])
```

which equals

```
test(1,2,3)
```

because you don't have control over Promise using call, use `bind` to determine the arguments

```
printData.apply.bind(printData, null)
```

which when called equals

```
printData.apply.bind(printData, null).call(undefined, [1,2,3])
>> 1 2 3
```

so Finally:

```
Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(printData.apply.bind(printData,null))
>> 1 2 3
```

Here's a related question about combining apply and call
[Why can I not call a function.apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306756/why-can-i-not-call-a-function-apply/42306772)

Answer (score 9):

One way using ES 6 **Destructuring**

```js
function printData(a,b,c){
   console.log(a,b,c)
}

Promise.all([1,2,3]).then( data => {var [a,b,c] = data;
                           printData(a,b,c);});
```

Using ES 6 **Spread** Syntax

```js
function printData(a,b,c){
   console.log(a,b,c)
}

Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(data => printData(...data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
.then(printData)
```

you can spread with

```
.then(args => printData(...args))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function printData(...a){
  console.log(a.reduce((n,o)=>n.concat(o),[]).join(","));
}
```

Take all arguments, reduce all Arrays in Arrays to one Array, pass it as arguments to console.log.

http://jsbin.com/vutizahago/edit?console

Comment: @lonewarrior556 really? have you tried Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(printData)