# Why can I not call a function.apply?

Tags: javascript

This is related to this question:
[Is it possible to spread the input array into arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304667/is-it-possible-to-spread-the-input-array-into-arguments/42304986)

I'm assuming that given this line of code:

```
Promise.all(array).then(foo)
```

`Promise.all` uses `Function.call`, to invoke `foo`,

```
foo.call(foo, arrayValues)
```

I would like to modify `foo` into a `foo.apply` function such that calling it with an array of values splits it into regular arguments.

Here is my train of thought....

Assuming I have this function

```
function test(a,b,c){
    console.log(a,b,c)
}
```

I can call this function using both `call` and `apply`

```
test.call(null,1,2,3)
>> 1 2 3
test.apply(null,[1,2,3])
>> 1 2 3
```

So far so good, this also works...

```
test.call.apply(test,[null,1,2,3])
>> 1 2 3
```

However I cannot get this to work

```
test.apply.call(test,[null,1,2,3])
>> undefined undefined undefined
```

What is happening here??

Comment: so... relevancy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.apply.call(test,[null,1,2,3])
```

equals to

```
test.apply([null,1,2,3])
```

equals to

```
test()
```

So you got undefined as output.

---

```
test.apply.call(test,null,[1,2,3])
```

equals to

```
test.apply(null,[1,2,3])
```

equals to

```
test(1,2,3)
```

This is right.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work

```
test.apply.call(test,null,[1,2,3])
>> 1 2 3
```

Comment: You got it to work, but didn't explain the "What is happening here??"